# Regular Expression to preserve quotes , single quotes , hyphens and split at white space

Tags: java, regex

I use Java Pattern class to specify the regex as a string.

So example
I love being spider-man : "Peter Parker"

should list spider-man and "Peter Parker" as a separate token.
Thanks

```
try {
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     String line = br.readLine();

     while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        line = br.readLine();
     }

    String everything = sb.toString();        
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("([\"'].*?[\"']|[^ ]+)");
    PatternTokenizer pt = new PatternTokenizer(new StringReader(everything),pat,0);
    while (pt.incrementToken()) {
     result.add(pt.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class).toString());

     }

 }
    catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
   }
```

So i guess the reason why "some word" is not working is because each token is itself a string.
Any cues ? Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using StringTokenizer?

Comment: No , i read that it is not a good practice to use it on SO itself. So i wanted  to use a patterntokenizer class of Lucene API that requires a regex expression to split the string into tokens.

Comment: I don't think you can use `split()` or something similar to handle this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether this regex is what you need:

```
"([\"'].*?[\"']|(?<=[ :]|^)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=[ :]|$))"
```

I assume that you don't have (single/double) quote inside (single/double) quote.

There is also assumption about the delimiter: I only allow space and `:` to work as delimiter. Nothing will be matched in `"foo_bar"`. If you want to add more delimiter, such as `;`, `.`, `,`, `?`, add it to the character class in both look ahead and look behind assertion, like this:

```
"([\"'].*?[\"']|(?<=[ :;.,?]|^)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=[ :;.,?]|$))"
```

Not yet tested on every input, but I have tested on this input:

```
"    sdfsdf \" sdfs  sdfsdfs \"   \"sdfsdf\"  sdfsdf   sdfsd  dsfshj sdfsdf-sdf  'sdfsdfsdf  sd f '  "
// I used replaceAll to check the captured group
.replaceAll("([\"'].*?[\"']|(?<=[ :]|^)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=[ :]|$))", "X$1Y")
```

And it works fine for me.

If you want a more liberal capturing, but still with the assumption about quoting:

```
"([\"'].*?[\"']|[^ ]+)"
```

To extract matches:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(inputString);
List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
while (m.find()) {
    tokens.add(m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Assuming it was for splitting a string, this doesn't work.It returns lot of empty tokens .

Comment: Even if it was for matching , only hyphens work but the quote part doesn't.

Comment: Just saw your updated regex! It works except for the fact that "some word" is being splitted as "some and word". any fixes? thank youu

Comment: @YuNo: `"some word"` works correctly for me (1 token), and `some word` will be split into 2 tokens. (JRE 7)

Comment: Thank you so much! works almost perfectly , i will figure something out for the quotes.

Comment: @YuNo: If you update your question with clearer examples, then probably you will get better help.

Comment: Updated the question. See if you can provide a better insight. Thanks!

Comment: @YuNo: Either you use my code with Matcher, or it won't work. Tokenizer cannot handle this kind of splitting elegantly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13764/discussion-between-nhahtdh-and-yuno)

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't have to be regex and your data in String is correct (quotes are in right order not like `" ' some data " '`) then you can do it in **one iteration** like

```
String data="I love being spider-man : \"Peter Parker\" or 'photo reporter'";

List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
boolean inSingleQuote=false;
boolean indDoubleQuote=false;

for (char c:data.toCharArray()){
    if (c=='\'') inSingleQuote=!inSingleQuote;
    if (c=='"') indDoubleQuote=!indDoubleQuote;
    if (c==' ' && !inSingleQuote && !indDoubleQuote){
        tokens.add(sb.toString());
        sb.delete(0,sb.length());
    }
    else 
        sb.append(c);
}
tokens.add(sb.toString());
System.out.println(tokens);
```

output

```
[I, love, being, spider-man, :, "Peter Parker", or, 'photo reporter']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!But sorry it has to be regex.Its for document tokenization.