# string manipulation in Java for extracting

Tags: java, string

I have a string like `delivery:("D1_0")`, how do i get the value inside the quotes alone from it. i.e `D1_0` alone from it.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Look in the API documentation of class `java.lang.String` for methods that you could use for this. Try to write some code yourself. If you still don't succeed, post your code and ask a more specific question.

Comment: you could split the string or extract your part with regex

Comment: what should I say... the_string.remove("deliveri:(\"").remove("\")");

Answer (score 2):

You could use regualr expresion like `\"(.*?)\"` to find that group, or even better, iterate over your String looking for quote marks `"` and reading characters inside of them until you find another quote mark. Something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11443609/1393766).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
int i = stringvariable.indexOf("(");
int j = stringvariable.indexOf(")");
String output = stringvariable.substring(i+2, j-2);
```

You will get the required value in output variable.

Answer (score 0):

"If your String is always in this format you can use

```
String theString = "delivery:(\"D1_0\")";
String array[] = theString.split("\"");
String result = array[1];   // now result string is D1_0

// Note: array[0] contains the first part(i.e "delivery:(" ) 
// and array[2] contains the second (i.e ")" )
```

Answer (score 0):

If your string is constant, in that the beginning of the string will not change, you could use the slice function

In Javascript:

```
        var text='delivery:("D1_0")';
        alert(text.slice(11, 15)); //returns "D1_0"
```

In Java:

```
String text = "delivery:(\"D1_0\")";
String extract = text.substring(11, 15);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
String str = "delivery:(\"D1_0\")";
String arr[] = str.split("[:\"()]"); //you will get arr[delivery, , , D1_0], choose arr[3]      
System.out.println(arr[3]);
```